# Civicrm Reporting

Tags: civireport

In Civicrm in Contact reports I used the template called Relationships. Our data is as follows:

We have Household Members, those members reside in a Residential Community(in our cases Caravan Parks with a unique name) and those Residential Communities are then grouped into branches.(example Ballina Branch)

So after checking the following report settings:

Contact A Full Name

Contact B Full name

Then set the following Filters:
Contact Type A is one of Residential Community, then Contact Type B is one of Household

the report shows the contact A is for example Ballina Caravan Park(which is the Residential Community Name) then Contact B is Mr and Mrs Smith(which is the Household name) however when trying to filter by the Group(which is the Branch Name) the report generates no information. Remove the Group and the report shows all Households in every Residential Community across all 17 branches. I cant seem to narrow the filter to a specific branch using the group filter.

Any ideas if im making a mistake?

Thanks so much...lost too much hair already!

Comment: What version of Civi are you using?

Comment: What version of Civi are you using?  What type is a Residential Community - an organisation?   Are the Branches static or smart groups?   I'd check whether the report is looking for a group of Contact A's (ie Residential Community) or Contact B's (ie Household).  You could try creating a group of Households to see what the report does with that.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. Residential Community is Type Organisation. the branches are static. Contact A is the Residential Community and Contact B is the Household. The issue is that i can get the report to show the Residential Community, and the Household, but cant filter by Branch. Its either showing me every branch or none. On top of that i cant include each households address. Im assuming i need to get a custom report built? Using Civi 4.7.7

Comment: Just tried that on the demo & it seems to do the right thing... http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/39

Answer (score 2):

Like Aidan, I too was able to create and filter the report according to what I believe it is you are describing - to clarify:

1. Residential Community has a contact type of "Organization" = Contact A, total number of organizations = 4
2. Households = Contact B - total number of households = 4, each related to one of the 4 Residential Communities (a.k.a Organizations)
3. Relationship of Contact A to Contact B = Resident is
4. Relationship of Contact B to COntact A = Resident of
5. Residential Community (a.k.a Organization) are statically grouped by Branch - total number of branches = 2 made up of 2 Residential Communities (a.k.a Organizations)

See screenshot below for report results, first WITHOUT group filter, then WITH group filter:

[image]

Hope this helps!